# Why adb sync leads to boot failure while make snod works fine?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build a custom rom in AOSP angler-debug (Nexus6p, 8.0).


Full build works fine.Then I change some code in
`framework/base/core/java/..`
and run 
`mmma framework/base`
to rebuild the framework.

Here is the problem :

When I use `adb sync` to update framework, it leads to boot failure: 

"didn't find class "com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider on path: ...."

"No original dex files found for dex location /system/priv-app/SettingsProvider/SettingsProvider.apk"

When I use `make snod` and `fastboot flashall` to flash system image, the device can boot correctly and the modified code effects.

Question :
Is there something different between these two commands?

Answer (score 0):

There are some mechanisms in framework to make sure the framework.jar is the original one when device is flashed. It seems that other parts of framework does not have this limitation.

In my experience, if your change codes other than `framework/base`, `adb sync` is fine, otherwise flash system image to avoid weird things.

You should feel lucky that building speed is way faster in AOSP 8, when I worked with AOSP 5, build the `framework/base` is a disaster.